# VueJS: How To Collapse Elements In A For Loop Separately?

Tags: vue.js

I like to toggle the `topic.text` property. I want to **collapse** AND **expand** it alternately.

I have the following setup:

```
<template v-for="topic in $store.state.forum.topics">
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="date">{{ topic.user }}, {{ topic.date }}</div>
    <span class="title">{{ topic.title }}</span>
    <div class="text">{{ topic.text }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What is the difference between collapsed and expanded?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<template v-for="topic in $store.state.forum.topics">
  <div class="topic" @click="toggleCollapsation">
    <div class="date">{{ topic.user }}, {{ topic.date }}</div>
    <span class="title">{{ topic.title }}</span>
    <div class="text" v-show="isCollapsed">{{ topic.text }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isCollapsed: false
      };
    },
    methods: {
      toggleCollapsation() {
        this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Instead of v-show you can also use v-if. The differences are (from the official docs):

> **v-if vs v-show**
>
> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event
> listeners and child components inside the conditional block are
> properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.
>
> v-if is also lazy:
> if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything -
> the conditional block won’t be rendered until the condition becomes
> true for the first time.
>
> In comparison, v-show is much simpler - the
> element is always rendered regardless of initial condition, with just
> simple CSS-based toggling.
>
> Generally speaking, v-if has higher toggle
> costs while v-show has higher initial render costs. So prefer v-show
> if you need to toggle something very often, and prefer v-if if the
> condition is unlikely to change at runtime.
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

I wouldn't read the topics directly from the $store global though. Assuming you're using VueX, I would use mapGetters in the parent view and feed the topic's component through props.

For added sugar you can take a look at Vue transitions: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html